# How to have an object both implicitly and explicitly types

Tags: typescript

I have an object which I want to explicitly type to catch type errors:

```
const hierarchy: HierarchyTree = {
   app: {
      events: {},
   },
   contact: {
   },
}
```

So far so good, but I also want to be able to infer it, so that using a helper giving me all paths grabbing the keys would still work (e.g. `Helper<typeof hierarchy> --> ["app"] | ["app", "events"] | ["contact"]`.

Currently I have either or - explicitly typing will break inference and without I will loose the type safety of the object itself. Can I achieve both?

Comment: @ekimboran No, I have the helper - the problem is that the helper won't be able to infer the type if the object is explicitly typed

Comment: this works for me https://shorturl.at/gpv24 do you mean that the object may include properties that are not included in the `HierarchyTree` type but you want them to be included in the `Helper<>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of explicitly typing the variable using a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables), or just using inference without any sort of check, you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to give you the best of both worlds.  For example, assuming `HierarchyTree` looks like

```
interface HierarchyTree {
  [k: string]: HierarchyTree;
}
```

You can write:

```
const hierarchy = {
  app: {
    events: {},
  },
  contact: {
  },
} satisfies HierarchyTree;

type MyHierarchy = typeof hierarchy
/* type MyHierarchy = {
    app: {
        events: {};
    };
    contact: {};
} */
```

That preserves the type of `hierarchy` enough for any utility type to pull out the information you need.  And it checks against `HierarchyTree`.  If you made a mistake, there would be a compiler error:

```
const badHierarchy = {
  app: 123 // error! Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'HierarchyTree'
} satisfies HierarchyTree;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBLGnKCAWBPAFSghQG8BYAKGWQG0BrALmQGcwpQBzAXWfU2z4iJANxUAvlSoIA9iDbIcGKFlx5kAXmQVqyOAAd9zHTRoQAbhHAtj4gDRUa9x8lnhEYYy+eVxrOGDALDAYLGjKqkLEEGKUVGB4+igAsnj8KoLqWglJMjCKEZlUAPQAVMg5KWmFapraLjQGRvW6pqYWVmA22uKxbb0NrnJgHraxfqXFUpRuCgBGcAAm6ZFZLY2GzACMAEwAzMjFxcjQUDJQAITIBIkoAOQgAK4AtnPQd8hByCAyYHosLGAnBAcDmABsUGAZBVbsg7itMsIIHcJP5AsFQuEBGokUA)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!